# php show a part of a multi array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have a multi array like this

```
$data = [
    array ( 
        "foo" => "lalala", 
        "moo" => [
            array ( "x" => "1", "x" => "100" ),
            array ( "x" => "2", "x" => "200" ),
        ]
    ),

    array (
        "foo2" => "foo2"
    )
]
```

How can I reference it with PHP "by name"?

Right now I do it with `[0]` - to get the "first" array:

```
$result = $data[0]['moo'] ;
```

But I wana reference it by "name" so something like this:

```
$result = $data->moo ;
```

What gives me then just the array part from moo?

Comment: You can only reference objects by name as you are trying to do. You can iterate over each array and cast them to objects, which you can then reference using properties.

Comment: basicly this for a navigation with subnavigation elements.  would you recommend doing this with objects instead of array ? basicly i dont realy get whats the difference between object and array . i will read about it .  i thought there must be some easy way without any loop or restructure.

Comment: Json_encode, and then json_decode. You will get the object.

Comment: I don't think objects are what you are looking for. If I understand you correctly, you want to get rid of the numeric 1st level. Maybe something like `array_column($data, 'moo')` will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Are you searching for something like this?

```
$data = Array(
    (object) Array(
        "foo" => "sad"
    ),
    (object) Array(
        "foo" => "sadsas"
    )
);

foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    if(isset($row->foo))
        echo $row->foo.'<br>';
}
```